# How to create UI with Mozilla Add-on SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xul

I want to crate an extension for Mozilla Firefox which processes HTML code and generates screen reader output in a new window. I need to create a UI window (without tabs, panels, and addressbar) and I've only found a tab and window method in SDK API which opens a new tab or a new browser window, but I need a custom window with my buttons.

I've started building an overlay extension with a window in XUL, but this is an old type of extension. So, I decided to make a restartless extension.

How can I make a user interface with SDK? Is it a good practice if I use XUL window in SDK?

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I´ve done an overlay extension, with a window in XUL. Then i just started creating a new extension with SDK from scratch, i´ve followed the guide from MDN, i´ve created a button in the panel, and all i can open is a tab or browser window, but i don´t need the tabs bar, the panel and address bar. And I wonder if there is any way to do the same window with SDK, and I don´t know if it´s a good practice to use a XUL window in SDK extension.

Comment: All I found about building interfaces is: The SDK generally expects you to specify your user interface using HTML, not XUL.

Comment: This repo is a basic demo addon that creates an HTML page (as xhtml) which allows localization, you can then open your xhtml page in the new tab or browser or panel :) https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/xhtml-xul it also shows you xul if you want to go xul route (of course with localization) :)

Comment: Tank your for your help, but i´ve done the same as you and the problem I have is that i need a new window without tabs, address bar and without toolbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the use of the [panel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) or simply loading a HTML page from the addon XPI into a tab and using [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) is encouraged for addon UIs.

If you really want to open a separate window with a completely custom layout you can use [window/utils#open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#open%28uri.2C_options%29). HTML is preferred (you can just use a `* {unset: all}` + some flexbox styles to get basic XUL-like behavior).

If you want the addon to directly interact with the window (instead of message-passing) you should open it with chrome privileges, otherwise it might get moved into the content process with e10s which would break direct access from addon code.

Comment: Thank´s. This solution open´s a new wiindow. I´ve tried with: var { open } = require('sdk/window/utils'); var window = open(self.data.url('ui/output.html')); I´m getting a new window, but i can´t open firebug and i can´t make right click. Is there any way to open firebug in that window?

Comment: you might have to pass additional parameters to `open()` for the context menu. For debugging, use the browser toolbox instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox